# React Native app fails unexpectedly after successful build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, npm

Running `npx react-native run-ios` returns a success prompt but the app closes immediately after launching? No errors are being displayed besides an apple alert stating that the application "unexpectedly quit"

I was initially getting some missing package errors but now those have been resolved and I've hit a wall

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the question by attempting to build my application using Xcode, the following error appeared:

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CreativeKitSetupException', reason: 'This application’s info.plist is missing <metadata> values for the key “LSApplicationQuerySchemes” required by the Login Kit SDK.'
```

Be sure to check your info.plist and make sure that it is properly configured. Hope this helps someone that runs into a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the snapchat SDK you must follow the Snap Kit Developer Portal Setup specified in the documentation [snapchatdocs](https://docs.snap.com/snap-kit/creative-kit/Tutorials/react-native#react-native-app-setup)

In summary as of 2023 you must register your app with the developer portal and enable the service at the bottom of the page.

then add the following to your `info.plist`

```
LSApplicationQueriesSchemes (string-array)  This should contain snapchat, bitmoji-sdk, and itms-apps.
SCSDKClientId (string)  The OAuth Client ID you received from registering your app on the developer portal.
SCSDKRedirectUrl (string)   The URL Snapchat will redirect to if there’s an error. This is the one that you added in the developer portal during the Snap Kit developer portal setup.
URL Types / Document Role (string)  Set it to Editor.
URL Types / URL Identifier (string) Set it to the app's Bundle ID, ie. $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER).
URL Types / URL Schemes (string-array)  Set it to a unique string (without space) to allow Snapchat to redirect back to your app after a successful authorization. For example, If your app's redirectUrl (refer to the SCSDKRedirectUrl key) is myapp://snap-kit/oauth2, then your scheme would be myapp.
```